# Calculate fibonacci in O(log n)

Tags: java, matrix, fibonacci-sequence

This program calculates the \$n\$th fibonacci number, in \$O(\log n)\$ time. I'm looking for code review, optimizations, and best practices.

```
public final class Fibo {

    private Fibo() { }

    public static int getNthfibo(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The fibo value cannot be negative");
        }

        if (n <= 1) return n;

        int[][] result = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}; // identity matrix.
        int[][] fiboM = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}};

        while (n > 0) {
            if (n%2 == 1) {
                multMatrix(result, fiboM);
            }
            n = n / 2;
            multMatrix(fiboM, fiboM);
        }

        return result[1][0];
    }

    private static void multMatrix(int[][] m, int [][] n) {
        int a = m[0][0] * n[0][0] +  m[0][1] * n[1][0];
        int b = m[0][0] * n[0][1] +  m[0][1] * n[1][1];
        int c = m[1][0] * n[0][0] +  m[1][1] * n[0][1];
        int d = m[1][0] * n[0][1] +  m[1][1] * n[1][1];

        m[0][0] = a;
        m[0][1] = b;
        m[1][0] = c;
        m[1][1] = d;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(getNthfibo(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small nitpick: `n = n / 2;` can just be `n /= 2;`.

Comment: `int c = m[1][0] * n[0][0] +  m[1][1] * n[0][1];` is wrong, it should end with `n[1][0]`. (But it still works because `n` is `fiboM` which is a symmetric matrix.)

Comment: How can I use this way to find general series? I mean, not starting with 0 and 1, but for example, starting from 9 and 5, then 9+5 = 14, 14+9 = 23, 23+14.....??

Answer (score 7):

Your code seems to be working properly so there is not much to say on this.

The only changes I would perform would be to make things easier to understand through different little steps.

- Multiplication could return a result

  At the moment, your multiplication procedure stores the result in the first argument. First issue is that it cannot be generalised to product of non-square matrices. The second issue is that it can make things a bit hard to understand when looking at the code using your function (`getNthfibo` in your case). It is a fairly easy change to perform :

  ```
  private static int[][] multMatrix(int[][] m, int [][] n) {
      int a = m[0][0] * n[0][0] +  m[0][1] * n[1][0];
      int b = m[0][0] * n[0][1] +  m[0][1] * n[1][1];
      int c = m[1][0] * n[0][0] +  m[1][1] * n[0][1];
      int d = m[1][0] * n[0][1] +  m[1][1] * n[1][1];
      int[][] ret = {
          {a, b},
          {c, d}};
      return ret;
  }
  ```

  and in your main function:

  ```
  result = multMatrix(result, fiboM);` and `fiboM = multMatrix(fiboM, fiboM);
  ```
- The signature of the `multMatrix` method lets us think that is works for any matrices.

  Actually, it only works for 2*2 matrices. This should be documented and checked at runtime (because it doesn't seem to be possible to do so at compilation time).
- Making Mathematics a bit more obvious

  Values can be reformatted in such a way that the mathematics behind are easier to understand. Also, a little bit of comment can help.

  ```
      int[][] result = {
          {1, 0},
          {0, 1}};

      /*         n
       * [ 1 1 ]     [ F(n+1) F(n)   ]
       * [ 1 0 ]   = [ F(n)   F(n-1) ]
       */
      int[][] fiboM = {
          {1, 1},
          {1, 0}};
  ```

Answer (score 7):

### Using `int` as a return value for Fibonacci

I've changed `main` thus:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + getNthfibo(i));
}
```

Sample output from the above code:

```
45 1134903170
46 1836311903
47 -1323752223
48 512559680
```

Fibonacci is an exponentially growing series. So by \$F\$<sub>47</sub> you are out of the range of `int`. \$O(n)\$ and \$O(log n)\$ are asymptotic performance statements, and you may not have received much benefit from it for input sizes \$0 <= n < 47\$.

`int` has 31 significant bits, `double` has 52/53 significant bits. So you could just use the closed form of Fibonacci series to calculate \$F\$<sub>n</sub> up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in **constant time** (using doubles and rounding to nearest int), if linear was too slow w.r.t. logarithmic time.